# How to kill a Python-Shell module process in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am currently using the python-shell module in a Node based web interface. The issue I am having is mostly syntactical. The code below shows the generation of a python script.

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
PythonShell.run('my_script.py' function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('finished');
}):
```

This is just an example script from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell/). How do I relate this to node's

```
var procc = require('child_process'.spawn('mongod');
procc.kill('SIGINT');
```

The documentation states that PythonShell instances have the following properties:

**childProcess: the process instance created via child_process.spawn**

*But how do I acutally use this? There seems to be a lack of examples when it comes to this specific module*

Answer (score 6):

For example -

```html
var python_process;

router.get('/start_python', function(req, res) {
    const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");

var options = {
    pythonPath:'local python path'
  }
    var pyshell = new PythonShell('general.py');

    pyshell.end(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    python_process = pyshell.childProcess;

    res.send('Started.');
});

router.get('/stop_python', function(req, res) {
   python_process.kill('SIGINT');
   res.send('Stopped');
});
```

Comment: is router referring to the module router?

Comment: This is just an example to show you how to use "childProcess". You can use app or any other middleware that can accept requests.